# Syntax error in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got this script from the web and I've manipulated it to fit my way but it tells me syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $Addr = localStorage.getItem('eaddress');
  $email7 = $('#email7')

  if ($Addr !== null) {
    $('#email7').val($Addr);

  }


   if ($Addr != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ans.php",
            data: $("#form2").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#log_msg').html(data);
                var result = $.trim(data);
                if(result==="ok"){
                window.location = 'page.html';
            }

            }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a bunch of bracing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $Addr = localStorage.getItem('eaddress');

    if ($Addr) {
        $('#email7').val($Addr);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ans.php",
            data: $("#form2").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#log_msg').html(data);
                var result = $.trim(data);
                if (result === "ok") {
                    window.location = 'page.html';
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Not absolutely required, but I also added `var` to local variables, simplified and combined and `if` test and removed a local variable not being used.

In the future, you can paste a block of code into http://jshint.com/ and it will show you where you've gone wrong.  It also makes other recommendations for robust code.

Comment: Why the downvote?  At least explain why you downvote so the answer can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

Close all semicolons and braces: add `});}` before very last `});`

Result:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $Addr = localStorage.getItem('eaddress');
    $email7 = $('#email7')

    if ($Addr != null) {
        $('#email7').val($Addr);

    }


    if ($Addr !== '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ans.php",
            data: $("#form2").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#log_msg').html(data);
                var result = $.trim(data);
                if (result === "ok") {
                    window.location = 'page.html';
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
```